# Why is my custom combobox not showing the selected value

Tags: wpf, mvvm, custom-controls

Can anybody please help me. I've created a custom combobox which has an itemtemplate,i'm binding the selected item but i cant see it as a selected item in the combo box.
Here is the code:

the xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <hcw:ClassificationSelectorThreeLayerComboBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedValue,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding CarePlanCatalogs.AllLinkedClassifications}" Margin="3,3,20,3"/>
</Grid>
```

the viewmodel:

```
class NeedViewModel : CarePlanEntityViewModelBase
{
    public LinkedClassification SelectedValue
    {
        get { return selectedValue; }
        set 
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                selectedValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedValue");
            }
        }
    }
}


<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<DataTemplate x:Key="ClassificationSelectorThreeLayerDataTemplate">
    <Border BorderBrush="#ACACAC" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=ClassificationComponent.ComponentName}" Margin="0,0,0,4" />
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=MainClass.MainClassName}" Margin="0,0,0,4"  />
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=SubClass.SubClassName}" Margin="0,0,0,4"  />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>

</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Do you see the values binded by the ItemsSource and are just missing the right selection or don't you see any item?

Comment: @MatthiasG : yes i can see them.

Comment: Then I guess you have an issue with your binding. Have you got any binding errors in the debug output? Maybe you could write a more detailed part of your viewmodel (especially with the source of SelectedItem and ItemsSource).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work with regular combobox?

Do you set SelectedValue to one of instances of LinkedClassification from CarePlanCatalogs.AllLinkedClassifications or create another instance? If you create another instance, you should override Equals and GetHashCode on LinkedClassification, so wpf could find your LinkedClassification in CarePlanCatalogs.AllLinkedClassifications

Comment: yeah i am creating another instance... overriding equals and GetHashCode?

Comment: Yes. There is an article in MSDN, which can help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bsc2ak47.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do you set SelectedValue to one of instances of LinkedClassification from CarePlanCatalogs.AllLinkedClassifications or create another instance?

If you create another instance, you should override Equals and GetHashCode on LinkedClassification, so wpf could find your LinkedClassification in CarePlanCatalogs.AllLinkedClassifications